# Using the Cookies middleware gives undefined value

Tags: javascript, node.js, curl, cookies

I am using the [`Cookies`](https://github.com/pillarjs/cookies) middleware in `Connect` to get some cookies. My code is this:

```
var connect = require("connect");
var Cookies = require("cookies");
connect()
  .use(Cookies.express(["key"]))
  .use(function(req,res){
    console.log(req.cookies.get("foo"));
    console.log(req.cookies.get("baz"));
    res.end();
  })
  .listen(8080)
```

I am using `curl` to send two cookies with the name `foo` and `baz` and I expect the output to be their values in the console. However, I get this:

```
bar, baz=tax
undefined
```

My `curl` request looks like this:

```
curl http://localhost:8080/ -H "Cookie: foo=bar, baz=tax"
```

How do I get just the values on separate lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your curl call is wrong should be:

```
curl http://localhost:8080/ -H "Cookie: foo=bar; baz=tax"
```

Use `;` instead of `,`